# Generating JSON with RABL, using a collection as a child node of the root object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I am trying to generate JSON using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), my `index.rabl` view looks like this:

```
collection @products => :products
  attributes :id, :name, :price, :category_id

node(:total) {@products.count}
```

This generates JSON with the following structure:

```
{"products":[{"id":1,"name":"product name","price":0.00,"category_id":1,"total":30}, 
             {"id":2,"name":"product2 name","price":0.00,"category_id":1,"total":30},...]}
```

However, i would like the structure of the generated JSON to look like this:

```
{  "products":[{"id":1,"name":"product name","price":0.00,"category_id":1}, 
               {"id":2,"name":"product2 name","price":0.00,"category_id":1},...],  
   "total":30
}
```

This means i would like to get the `"total":30` out of the `"products"` array and put it into the root object of the generated JSON. What changes do i need to make to my view file to generate the required JSON? I have very little experience with RABL and help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **index.json.rabl** you can do this:

```
object false
child @events do
  attributes :id, :message
end
node(:count) { @events.size }
```

The result is:

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 124,
            "message": "Hola"
        },
        {
            "id": 123,
            "message": "Chau"
        },
        {
            "id": 122,
            "message": "Yeah baby!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tested this on my project. You can change events with products...